# Clone Repository on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: github, visual-studio-2022

I have a question. So me and my friends are working on a vending machine project on C#. We use Github to store files.

My friends are using Windows and I'm using a Mac. They're using Visual Studio 2019 and I somehow cannot use that 2019 version on my Mac, so I have to use the 2022 version.

They were able to clone repository easily from Github, but on my Mac, it doesn't work. Is it because of different version?

I tried redoing it so many times

Comment: Try cloning it from the command line with command-line Git and include the full contents of the error message here as a text block by editing your question.  There are many reasons it might not be working and without more details we can't help you fix it.  Also include information about whether you're using HTTPS or SSH and how you've set up your personal access token or SSH key, as appropriate.